# Big-O complexity -> finding if the array element sum to a target

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o

The question is about the coding bat problem [Determine if there exists a group of numbers in the array of ints which sums to a target.](https://codingbat.com/prob/p145416)

below is the standard solutions in java

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  final int len = nums.length;

  if (start == len) {
    return target == 0;
  }

  if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) {
      return true;
  } 
  if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;     
}
```

It seems like the above algorithm can be broken down into a recursive solution:

> T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + O(n⁰)

And using [subtract and conquer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/master-theorem-subtract-conquer-recurrences/) the Big-O time complexity comes out to be

**O(2^n)**? Is that correct?

Does the fact that the recursive call happens in an if-statement makes a difference on the complexity?

Comment: *"happens in an if-statement"* is a misleading phrase. In the code `if (foo()) { bar(); }`, which would you say happens *in* the if-statement? `foo()` or `bar()`? Let me change the code to make it clearer `boolean b = foo(); if (b) { bar(); }` and then ask again: Which would you say happens *in* the if-statement? --- BTW: That re-write of the code should have answered your question: No, having the method call in the *condition* part of the if-statement makes no difference, since it is always executed.

Comment: _Having the method call in the condition part of the if-statement makes no difference, since it is always executed_ Nuff said right there. Spare yourself the english nitpicks. :)Though my question is only partially answered through this.

Comment: *"Though my question is only partially answered"* That's why it's written as a comment, not an answer, since it is not answering the full question. --- As for nitpicking, when writing code what you write matters, because the code does what you wrote, not what you meant to write. For writing text to people, you *can* be more lax, but applying some of the same precision you use when writing code, helps prevent confusion and misunderstandings. My "english nitpick" was to let you know how your question could be misunderstood, and that you should be *clearer* when asking questions.

Comment: Well to be fair....I don't see how that misunderstanding arises, especially when I have pasted the code itself which shows precisely where in if construct recursion is called. If it's in the statement or the body, it's t-h-e-r-e for everyone to see, also It's probably lax on the reader's part to ignore the code I wrote in my question.

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short, you need to check (in the worst case scenario that we all love) all permutations of your `n` elements.

So it doesn't matter if the code is run in if statements or otherwise, the number of combinations stays the same...

Of course, if you use heuristics, and all kinds of other tricks to cut down (in a meaningful way) the number of checks you need to do, that could change the picture. But in your question you do not address any of that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the complexity is `O(2^N)`. At each position, you have two choices:

1. Take the item.
2. Don't take the item.

You have 2 ways at each step and you have N number of decisions to make, so it's a total of `2^N`. The fact that you write it inside the if condition or not doesn't make a difference. The speedup is barely noticeable.

PS: This is a standard problem of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which can be solved in much lesser time

Comment: _This is a standard problem of the subset sum problem which can be solved in much lesser time_ Do you mean there complexity can be lesser than O(2^n)?

Comment: @Andreas Proof?

Comment: @Anirudh Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. Thought it was looking for *consecutive* groups of numbers.

Comment: @Anirudh, yes. You can achieve time complexity less than 2^N using dynamic programming.